# Combine current element with next element in a list

Tags: python, python-3.x, string, list

I'm quite embarassed because of this question but i just want to combine the current element in a list with the next element. The list is given as:

```
['scalar2_q1p2_114(-2,-2) =', '0', 'scalar2_q1p2_114(-2,-1) =', '0',
 'scalar2_q1p2_114(-2,0) =', '0', 'scalar2_q1p2_114(-2,1) =', '0',
 'scalar2_q1p2_114(-2,2) =', '0', 'scalar2_q1p2_114(-1,-2) =', '0',
 'scalar2_q1p2_114(-1,-1) =', '0', 'scalar2_q1p2_114(-1,0) =', '0',
 'scalar2_q1p2_114(-1,1) =', '0', 'scalar2_q1p2_114(-1,2) =', '0',
 'scalar2_q1p2_114(0,-2) =', '0', 'scalar2_q1p2_114(0,-1) =', '0',
 'scalar2_q1p2_114(0,0) =', '0', 'scalar2_q1p2_114(0,1) =', '0',
 'scalar2_q1p2_114(0,2) =', '0', 'scalar2_q1p2_114(1,-2) =', '0',
 'scalar2_q1p2_114(1,-1) =', '0', 'scalar2_q1p2_114(1,0) =', '0',
 'scalar2_q1p2_114(2,-2) =', '0', 'scalar2_q1p2_114(2,-1) =', '0',
 'scalar2_q1p2_114(2,0) =', '0', 'scalar2_q1p2_114(1,2) =',
 'scalar2_q1p2_114(1,1)*((-d+3)/(SPD[p2,p2]))']
```

What I want is a list in a form of:

```
['scalar2_q1p2_114(-2,-2) = 0', ...].
```

Can anybody help me out with this small problem

Comment: `[f'{a} {b}' for a, b in zip(my_list[::2], my_list[1::2])]`

Answer (score 2):

You have to iterate through the list 2 elements at a time.

Try this.

```
[my_list[i]+my_list[i+1] for i in range(0,len(my_list)-1,2)] #my_list is the original list you've posted in the question
```

---

```
['scalar2_q1p2_114(-2,-2) =0',
 'scalar2_q1p2_114(-2,-1) =0',
 'scalar2_q1p2_114(-2,0) =0',
 'scalar2_q1p2_114(-2,1) =0',
 'scalar2_q1p2_114(-2,2) =0',
 'scalar2_q1p2_114(-1,-2) =0',
 'scalar2_q1p2_114(-1,-1) =0',
 'scalar2_q1p2_114(-1,0) =0',
 'scalar2_q1p2_114(-1,1) =0',
 'scalar2_q1p2_114(-1,2) =0',
 'scalar2_q1p2_114(0,-2) =0',
 'scalar2_q1p2_114(0,-1) =0',
 'scalar2_q1p2_114(0,0) =0',
 'scalar2_q1p2_114(0,1) =0',
 'scalar2_q1p2_114(0,2) =0',
 'scalar2_q1p2_114(1,-2) =0',
 'scalar2_q1p2_114(1,-1) =0',
 'scalar2_q1p2_114(1,0) =0',
 'scalar2_q1p2_114(2,-2) =0',
 'scalar2_q1p2_114(2,-1) =0',
 'scalar2_q1p2_114(2,0) =0',
 'scalar2_q1p2_114(1,2) =scalar2_q1p2_114(1,1)*((-d+3)/(SPD[p2,p2]))']
```

Answer (score 2):

you can use list comprehension with `zip` built-in function:

```
l = ['scalar2_q1p2_114(-2,-2) =', '0', 'scalar2_q1p2_114(-2,-1) =', '0',
 'scalar2_q1p2_114(-2,0) =', '0', 'scalar2_q1p2_114(-2,1) =', '0',
 'scalar2_q1p2_114(-2,2) =', '0', 'scalar2_q1p2_114(-1,-2) =', '0',
 'scalar2_q1p2_114(-1,-1) =', '0', 'scalar2_q1p2_114(-1,0) =', '0',
 'scalar2_q1p2_114(-1,1) =', '0', 'scalar2_q1p2_114(-1,2) =', '0',
 'scalar2_q1p2_114(0,-2) =', '0', 'scalar2_q1p2_114(0,-1) =', '0',
 'scalar2_q1p2_114(0,0) =', '0', 'scalar2_q1p2_114(0,1) =', '0',
 'scalar2_q1p2_114(0,2) =', '0', 'scalar2_q1p2_114(1,-2) =', '0',
 'scalar2_q1p2_114(1,-1) =', '0', 'scalar2_q1p2_114(1,0) =', '0',
 'scalar2_q1p2_114(2,-2) =', '0', 'scalar2_q1p2_114(2,-1) =', '0',
 'scalar2_q1p2_114(2,0) =', '0', 'scalar2_q1p2_114(1,2) =',
 'scalar2_q1p2_114(1,1)*((-d+3)/(SPD[p2,p2]))']

[f + ' ' + s for f, s in zip(l[::2], l[1::2])]
```

**output:**

```
['scalar2_q1p2_114(-2,-2) = 0',
 'scalar2_q1p2_114(-2,-1) = 0',
 'scalar2_q1p2_114(-2,0) = 0',
 'scalar2_q1p2_114(-2,1) = 0',
 'scalar2_q1p2_114(-2,2) = 0',
 'scalar2_q1p2_114(-1,-2) = 0',
 'scalar2_q1p2_114(-1,-1) = 0',
 'scalar2_q1p2_114(-1,0) = 0',
 'scalar2_q1p2_114(-1,1) = 0',
 'scalar2_q1p2_114(-1,2) = 0',
 'scalar2_q1p2_114(0,-2) = 0',
 'scalar2_q1p2_114(0,-1) = 0',
 'scalar2_q1p2_114(0,0) = 0',
 'scalar2_q1p2_114(0,1) = 0',
 'scalar2_q1p2_114(0,2) = 0',
 'scalar2_q1p2_114(1,-2) = 0',
 'scalar2_q1p2_114(1,-1) = 0',
 'scalar2_q1p2_114(1,0) = 0',
 'scalar2_q1p2_114(2,-2) = 0',
 'scalar2_q1p2_114(2,-1) = 0',
 'scalar2_q1p2_114(2,0) = 0',
 'scalar2_q1p2_114(1,2) = scalar2_q1p2_114(1,1)*((-d+3)/(SPD[p2,p2]))']
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use str.join and zip over every other element using slicing:

```
list(map('  '.join, zip(l[::2], l[1::2])))
```

---

```
['scalar2_q1p2_114(-2,-2) = 0',
 'scalar2_q1p2_114(-2,-1) = 0',
 'scalar2_q1p2_114(-2,0) = 0',
 'scalar2_q1p2_114(-2,1) = 0',
 'scalar2_q1p2_114(-2,2) = 0',
 'scalar2_q1p2_114(-1,-2) = 0',
 'scalar2_q1p2_114(-1,-1) = 0',
 'scalar2_q1p2_114(-1,0) = 0',
 'scalar2_q1p2_114(-1,1) = 0',
 'scalar2_q1p2_114(-1,2) = 0',
 'scalar2_q1p2_114(0,-2) = 0',
 'scalar2_q1p2_114(0,-1) = 0',
 'scalar2_q1p2_114(0,0) = 0',
 'scalar2_q1p2_114(0,1) = 0',
 'scalar2_q1p2_114(0,2) = 0',
 'scalar2_q1p2_114(1,-2) = 0',
 'scalar2_q1p2_114(1,-1) = 0',
 'scalar2_q1p2_114(1,0) = 0',
 'scalar2_q1p2_114(2,-2) = 0',
 'scalar2_q1p2_114(2,-1) = 0',
 'scalar2_q1p2_114(2,0) = 0',
 'scalar2_q1p2_114(1,2) = scalar2_q1p2_114(1,1)*((-d+3)/(SPD[p2,p2]))']
```